# RegEx to validate usernames

Tags: php, regex

I am not very good in Regular Expression, and can't seem to understand them quite well.

I am looking for a regular expression which will match and allow following strings for a username, with these conditions:

- username can: **start with a number or with a alphabetic letter**
- username can contain special chars: **dots, dashes, underscores**
- username must be in this range: **from 3 chars up to 32 chars.**
- alphanumeric characters in the username can be both: **lowercase** and **uppercase**
- cannot contain empty spaces

Almost similar to Twitter's and Facebook username patterns.

Please help me. Thank you.

FWI: I have tried this: `/^(?=.{1,15}$)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/` - and this does not satisfy my conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\._-]{2,31}$
```

this results in the php code

```
if (preg_match('~^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\._-]{2,31}$~', $username) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Starts with digit or alphabetic

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

can contain as above plus dots, dashes and underscores

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._-]
```

and all together

```
[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._-]{2, 31}
```

Answer (score 2):

**try this one this is working for me in every registration form**

```
//username Validation
var usernameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\[\]\.\-#']*$/i;
var username=document.getElementById('username');
if(username.value==""){
document.getElementById('lblusername').innerHTML="Username Required!";
username.focus();
return false;
}   
else if(usernameRegex.test(username.value)== false) 
{
document.getElementById('lblusername').innerHTML="Allow Alphanumeric Only! (E.g Demo123)";
username.focus();
return false;
}
else
{
document.getElementById('lblusername').innerHTML="";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z\-\._]{2,31}$
```